# Cardinality of the statement

Tags: set, logic, discrete-mathematics

What is the cardinality of the following statement?

> { x|x is a string over {a, b, c} and |x| <= 2}

And is every set closed under cross-product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick87's answer for (1) is correct and sufficient. For (2) here is some more context.

I assume you mean that by "Cross Product" you mean Cartesian product with itself. Any finite set cannot be closed under cross product with itself. Consider, for contradiction, we have some finite set A that is closed under cross product so A is subset of AxA. So let x be in A, so x is in AxA. Then x must be some pair (y,z) such that y,z are elements of A since x is in AxA. We can continue this logic indefinitely and we will get A must infinite. So A cannot be closed under cross product with itself if it is finite.

In a way A "is" a subset of AxA because A can be seen as **isomorphic** to {(x,x) | x in A} which is a subset of AxA. However that is up to an isomorphism and not directly equal.

A gut feeling from the above proof is that the union of A^n for all n would be closed under cross product.

Hope this helps with the cross product question.

Comment: Pretty basic question but it seems like you would know - is it pretty settled that A^n x A^m = A^(n+m) (where A^n is the set of n-tuples over A and x is the Cartesian product) or are there any holdouts that would write something like ((1,2),(3,4)) but not (1,2,3,4) for an element of N^2 x N^2?

Comment: Technically ((1,2),(3,4)) is the correct item but it would be easy to create an isomorphism that maps ((1,2),(3,4)) -> (1,2,3,4) so in my experience most people tend to ignore the technicalities and just write the easier (1,2,3,4) unless they are proving something that requires acknowledging the technical details

Answer (score 0):

(1) The set described is {"", "a", "b", "c", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", "bc", "ca", "cb", "cc"} and this set has cardinality 13 because there are 13 things in it.

(2) As I commonly understand it, no set is really closed under cross product, or at least most sets are not. I mean, if you have the set {0, 1} the cross product with itself is the set {(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)} which has four elements compared to the original set's two; so this should constitute a counterexample.